# Eevee Won't Clear the Color Buffer When I Render

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

What I mean by this is that for some reason, when I switch my rendering engine from Cycles to EEVEE, the object will look like this if you move around it

[image: messed up material]

The thing is, it's only this object. I even tried remaking all the materials but since I got it online, I think it might be something else because this didn't work.

EDIT:
It does the same thing in material view mode.

Comment: You might need to post this one for us to look at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ . But I am guessing overlapping geometry.

Comment: I would except that the file is too big to upload.

Comment: Cut down a copy of the file to show the issue, but first check for clean geometry